# jQuery to add a "new" image at the end of row if the row's date = today()

Tags: jquery, datetime

We have a table with two columns, `Date` and `News`. I would like to attach a `new.gif` image at the end of `News` string if that rows `Date` = `today()`.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="ms-vb2">
            <nobr>5/29/2015</nobr>    
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb2">
            <a href="http://xxxx">ABCABCABC</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating">
        <td class="ms-vb2">
            <nobr>5/31/2015</nobr>
        </td>
        <td class="ms-vb2">
            <a href="http://yyyyyy">ABCABCABC</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I do it with jQuery? Thanks for advice.

Comment: Please add your HTML and any JS code you've written yourself

Comment: HTML is added and no JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.each` to loop over the `tr` elements and read the date in the `nobr` element and compare it to the current date. If they match you can use `append()` to add the `img` element to the `a`. Try this:

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this);
    var date = new Date($tr.find('nobr').text());
    if (date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) === new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
        $tr.find('a').append('<img src="new.gif" />');
    }
});
```